# Can you access the IEnumerable as you are yield returning it?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

My code below finds all prime numbers below `number` by creating a list of primes and checking to see if the next potential prime is evenly divisible by any primes in the list.

I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of `yield return`. Right now I have a `List<int> primes` that I use inside the function. But I'm returning the same data via `yield return`. So my question is

> Can I access the IEnumerable< int > from inside the function as I am creating it? So I can remove the List< int > primes altogether.

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds all primes below <paramref name="number"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">The number to stop at</param>
/// <returns>All primes below <paramref name="number"/></returns>
private static IEnumerable<long> PrimeNumbers(long number)
{
    yield return 2;
    List<long> primes = new List<long>(2);          

    for(long num = 3; num < number; num += 2)
    {

        //if any prime lower then num divides evenly into num, it isn't a prime
        //what I'm doing now
        if(!primes.TakeWhile(x => x < num).Any(x => num % x == 0))
        {
            primes.Add(num);
            yield return num;
        }

        //made-up syntax for what I'd like to do
        if(!this.IEnumerable<long>
                .TakeWhile(x => x < num).Any(x => num % x == 0))
        {
            yield return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: There are better ways to get primes until a certain number. Check out Sieve of Sundaram: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram

Comment: You can also improve by going for Sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes and even more by going for Sieve of Atkin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin Which I think is one of the fastest ways known today to generate prime numbers (if not the fastest) and there is also pseudo code in wiki to help you getting started.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I saw those sieve's on wikipedia and if I were going to keep this code anywhere important I'd probably use them. This code was more to help train myself how to think in the `yield return` mindset.

Comment: So yes, you can't. But what you could do is have a class PrimesGenerator and make that list as a data member, so you don't have to regenerated primes every time again, but remember in another data member the biggest number you've checked and check for more numbers if needed at the current call for GenerateNumbers(max). The idea would be called "caching", since you cache data to be used again and again, for extra efficiency. It would still be as slow as now, but would be TONS faster if you call it for a max that has already been cached.

Comment: If you want my implementation for exactly that, I'll pastebin it for you.

Comment: @YoryeNathan those are good ideas. I don't need the code right now, this was just for a project euler question. thanks much for the tips though.

Comment: Oh that's the same reason I did it :) Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The compiler builds a state machine to implement `yield return`, and the calling code that enumerates through your enumerable is as much a part of its working as your code is. The compiler builds a hidden object that stores the current state of your code, including its call stack and locals, and it calls different pieces of your method as the caller invokes `Current` and `MoveNext`. Trying to enumerate your object from the beginning while another enumeration is in progress would mess up the ongoing enumeration, which would not be good.

In this particular case, you don't want it to happen either: the implementation of `yield return` does not store the values that you produce, so if even if you could access your own `IEnumerable` while enumerating, it would recursively call back itself multiple times to produce each new item, so it would take you ridiculously long time to produce even a moderate number of primes.

Comment: Of course you can.  Recursive or nested enumerations are supposed to be handled automatically, that's part of the beauty of them.  This would do it: `if(!PrimeNumbers(num).Any(x => num % x == 0)) yield return num`.  Just tested in LINQPad.  However your second point stands, that it is horribly inefficient.  You can tell this by simply doing a `Console.WriteLine(..)` inside the function to see just how many times it is enumerating the same result.

Comment: @mellamokb That's not accessing *itself* from the function that creates the sequence. It's accessing *an identical copy* of itself, with its own state, state machine, and everything else. That's why it does not break, and that's why it's so slow :)

Comment: Ah! I'm on the same page now :) Yes, you can't grab onto previous entries from the same instance because the previous state no longer exists.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so you are saying that I _shouldn't_ recalculate every single previous prime every time I want to calculate a new prime? haha, that sounds terrible.

Comment: @jb. Yeah, check out mellamokb's first comment to see just how terrible that would be. In fact, this algorithm for finding primes illustrates an important point about *dynamic programming* - you "pay" with memory for speeding up calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The overall enumerator isn't a container like `List<int> primes` is.  It is a "process" for finding primes.  If you recursively use your own process to generate the list of primes to work against for finding the next prime, you will be recursively enumerating the same results over and over again which will be extremely inefficient.  Consider what would happen (if you could actually do this) for finding the primes up to 10.

```
yield return 2
num = 3
IEnumerable<long>.TakeWhile(x => x < 3).Any(x => num % x == 0)
    new enumerator
    yield return 2
yield return 3
num = 4
IEnumerable<long>.TakeWhile(x => x < 4).Any(x => num % x == 0)
    new enumerator
    yield return 2
    num = 3
    IEnumerable<long>.TakeWhile(x => x < 3).Any(x => num % x == 0)
        new enumerator
        yield return 2
    yield return 3
num = 5
IEnumerable<long>.TakeWhile(x => x < 5).Any(x => num % x == 0)
    new enumerator
    yield return 2
    num = 3
    IEnumerable<long>.TakeWhile(x => x < 4).Any(x => num % x == 0)
        new enumerator
        yield return 2
        num = 3
        IEnumerable<long>.TakeWhile(x => x < 3).Any(x => num % x == 0)
            new enumerator
            yield return 2
        yield return 3
        num = 4
etc.
```

It's an exponentially increasing enumartion.  It's akin to naively finding fibonacci numbers by calculating `f(n-1) + f(n-2)`.  You're doing a lot of the same work over and over again, and even more so as you reach higher numbers.  The internal List of primes serves as a sort of cache to make your enumeration very efficient.